# Post Deployment JVM log validation for JBOSS and WAS Application

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, urbancode

We use Jenkins and Urban Code Deploy to do our builds and deployments respectively. Post the deployment we manually go ahead and validate the JVM logs. Most of the Applications we deploy are JBOSS and WAS8.5. I wanted some suggestion on automating this post deployment validation task. Is there any tool, plugin that can be integrated with Urban Code Deploy to perform this log parsing against certain keywords.

I have "Log parser" plugin which is an open source plugin in Jenkins. Are there any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UrbanCode Deploy you can use the step called "Monitor File Contents" to check if a regular expression is contained in a file.

Another way would be to output the log file content in a shell step, like `cat logfile`, and then use a post-processing script to check if an expression is in the file. In this case, you can use JavaScript syntax. [See](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.2.1/com.ibm.udeploy.doc/topics/comp_postProcess.html)